# React Native Build Error on IOS - typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, flipper

After upgrading React Native from 0.61.5 to 0.63.2, `Flipper` causes an error on IOS as `typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')`

On github there are a few proposed answers but none of them solved my problem https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/834

Is there anyone figured out how to solve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
you should disable these next few lines in your Podfile.

```
  # use_flipper!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
```

Comment: With react-native 0.63.4 need to comment below line
 # use_flipper!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end

Comment: Make sure you run pod update again after, otherwise build will still fail

Answer (score 11):

**STEP  1:**

Go to `YOUR_PROJECT > ios > Podfile` and then comment these lines

```
  # use_flipper!()

  # post_install do |installer|
  #   react_native_post_install(installer)
  #   __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  # end
```

**STEP 2:**

after step 1 you have to run `pod update` command on `YOUR_PROJECT > ios` path.

Bingo its done.

---

**IMPORTANT**

In case you get some errors after doing above 2 steps,

1. GO to `YOUR_PROJECT > ios > YOUR_PROJECT_NAME >` and run this command
2. `plutil ./Info.plist` it will show you where the issue is.
3. Then fix that issue from your text editor.

Comment: This should accepted the answer!. Save my day

Comment: This will work, but it will just disable the Flipper debugger for the app right, which could be very useful. Might be a temporary workaround.

Comment: Also I don't think you're supposed to also disable the `react_native_post_install(installer)` part.

Comment: 2023 and still this one is the correct answer hehe :)

Answer (score 8):

Directories name should not have space in which project exists.
This can also cause this error.

Comment: Theres no way this was the error... wow

Comment: This solution is "an answer" for some issues, but definitely not this issue. I have the same error as the author and there are no spaces whatsoever in our app directory. Thanks for taking the time to try helping, though. I don't want to discourage any newcomers.

Answer (score 7):

This is what solves for me for react native 0.65. It is very important that folly should link to 9.0

```
post_install do |installer|
react_native_post_install(installer)
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.delete "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  end
  case target.name
  when 'RCT-Folly'
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: this works for me, but dont know what is drawbacks for setting the " config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'" for 'RCT-Folly'  ???

Comment: I am following this but sadly Xcode throws linker command failed and gives no additional details. I am on M2 Mac running Xcode 15 and using RN 0.65.1

Answer (score 6):

First, remove the Flipper from your project.

After you go with this path.
Path: "Your-Project-App/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h"

Replace this code time.h

```js
/*
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <folly/portability/Config.h>

// OSX is a pain. The XCode 8 SDK always declares clock_gettime
// even if the target OS version doesn't support it, so you get
// an error at runtime because it can't resolve the symbol. We
// solve that by pretending we have it here in the header and
// then enable our implementation on the source side so that
// gets linked in instead.
#if __MACH__ &&                                                       \
        ((!defined(TARGET_OS_OSX) || TARGET_OS_OSX) &&                \
         (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_12)) || \
    (TARGET_OS_IPHONE)

#ifdef FOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME
#undef FOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME
#endif

#define FOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME 1
#define FOLLY_FORCE_CLOCK_GETTIME_DEFINITION 1

#endif

// These aren't generic implementations, so we can only declare them on
// platforms we support.
#if !FOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME && (defined(__MACH__) || defined(_WIN32))
#define CLOCK_REALTIME 0
#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC 1
#define CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID 2
#define CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID 3

typedef uint8_t clockid_t;
extern "C" int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec* ts);
extern "C" int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec* ts);
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
#define TM_YEAR_BASE (1900)

extern "C" {
char* asctime_r(const tm* tm, char* buf);
char* ctime_r(const time_t* t, char* buf);
tm* gmtime_r(const time_t* t, tm* res);
tm* localtime_r(const time_t* t, tm* o);
int nanosleep(const struct timespec* request, struct timespec* remain);
char* strptime(
    const char* __restrict buf,
    const char* __restrict fmt,
    struct tm* __restrict tm);
time_t timelocal(tm* tm);
time_t timegm(tm* tm);
}
#endif
```

After that, Please try to run the application via Xcode, Now the application can't run successfully you got another error

2nd Error is: "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

2nd Error solution in the screenshot,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Us1.png)

Answer (score 4):

Update your pod file with below code.

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' }) # update this part
 post_install do |installer|
   flipper_post_install(installer)
 end
```

Comment: you can find the version at https://cocoapods.org/pods/Flipper-Folly in "See Podspec", e.g. 2.6.10 right now

Answer (score 3):

I needed to specify the versions:

```rb
  # https://github.com/facebook/flipper/releases
  # https://cocoapods.org/pods/Flipper-Folly
  # https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenSSL-Universal
  use_flipper!({
    "Flipper" => "0.134.0",
    "Flipper-Folly" => "2.6.10",
    "OpenSSL-Universal" => "1.1.1100"
  })
```

And for a full Podfile, it might help:

```rb
require_relative "../node_modules/expo/scripts/autolinking"
require_relative "../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods"
require_relative "../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules"

platform :ios, "12.0"

target "socializus" do
  use_expo_modules!

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    path: config[:reactNativePath],
    hermes_enabled: false
  )

  # https://github.com/facebook/flipper/releases
  # https://cocoapods.org/pods/Flipper-Folly
  # https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenSSL-Universal
  use_flipper!({
    "Flipper" => "0.134.0",
    "Flipper-Folly" => "2.6.10",
    "OpenSSL-Universal" => "1.1.1100"
  })

  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    react_native_post_install(installer)

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, this error occurred because I was doing in the `ios/Podfile` the following:

```js
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end

  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
  end
```

I can only assume that setting the build target of the Folly target was messing with something. Once these lines were removed from my Podfile and `npx pod-install` was run, the build worked again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem with `RCT-Folly` and solved the issue following the ways below:

Basically, it comes from `../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb` file. Here is the code of that file.

```bash
  # But... doing so caused another issue in Flipper:
  #   "Time.h:52:17: error: typedef redefinition with different types"
  # We need to make a patch to RCT-Folly - remove the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` check.
  # See https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/834 for more details.
  time_header = "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root.to_s}/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h"
  `sed -i -e  $'s/ && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_10_0)//' #{time_header}`
```

If you edit the code in `node_modules`, the `.lock` file will be changed. So to be safe, you can update the `Podfile`.

1. Add this line of code

   `sed -i -e  $'s/__IPHONE_10_0/__IPHONE_12_0/' Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h`

   after the `post_install do |installer|` line in `Podfile` like the following code snippet

```bash
target 'AwesomeProjectTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    `sed -i -e  $'s/__IPHONE_10_0/__IPHONE_12_0/' Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h`
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

2. Run `cd ios` on the project root folder
3. Run `pod deintergrate` in the terminal and install pod again with the command `pod install`
4. Finally, build the project again with running the command `npx react-native run-ios` on the project root folder

Bingo! My issue has been solved as expected.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to remove Flipper from your app then go through this solution.

your pod.file like this

```
add_flipper_pods!('Flipper' => '0.74.0')
```

upgrade Flipper-Folly by doing this

remove this line  `add_flipper_pods!('Flipper' => '0.74.0')`

add this line `add_flipper_pods!('Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0')`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my XCode version was 11.5 and it was not supporting something newer in Flipper. Updating my XCode to version 12 fixed it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from react-native 0.65 to 0.68.
Deleted Pods and Podfile.lock and then ran `pod update` from within my iOS directory.
Didn't have to change any other code.

Thanks to @Sultan Aslam for mentioning `pod update`

Comment: This worked although I find that the `Time.h` error resolution exposed more errors behind it. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading node to 16.13.0 worked for me, then remove node modules and pods then reinstall it