# react-native can't build ios: (error xcode Flipper) Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, flipper

My goal is to run a react native build (ios version).

**Situation 1**

- Actions: start metro (ok)
- build ios.
  Problem: build failed with exit code 1.

```
(CompileC /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NAME_OF_PROJECT-gxlagomyefvmjkdemiakcfycxnhx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/macbook/Documents/work/omg/mobile/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler)
```

**Situation 2**

- Actions: build ios.
- Problem: Flipper:: `Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t'`

**Versions**

- xcode version 12.5
- ios 9+
- iphone 12

Some actions I tried that didn't work:

1. [solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ0uo.png)
2. [solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdQ7J.png)
3. reisntall all pods
4. update all pods
5. reclon project
6. - rm -Rf Pods/*
   - pod cache clean --all
   - pod install

---

and a few other little fixes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: checkout this answer, it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/73756361/4592295

Answer (score 9):

Change `Podfile` like below:

```
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    `sed -i -e  $'s/__IPHONE_10_0/__IPHONE_12_0/' Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h`
  end
```

Run `pod install` and it works!

Comment: make sure that you don't have spaces in any of your folders and directories (their names) !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue on my very first react-native project when I tried to run it on an ios simulator.

> clockid_t

`clockid_t` is part of one of your systems. The error is actually for redefining `clockid_t` twice.

Renaming `clockid_t` to something else solved my problem.
I renamed it from `clockid_t` to `clockid_tt` and then my project ran smoothly.

Because I'm a beginner react-native dev, I am not sure about whether this solution will create any future problems on my react-native project. Not yet faced any problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and you should disable these next few lines in your Podfile.


# use_flipper!()
#  post_install do |installer|
#    react_native_post_install(installer)
#   __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
#  end

**OR**

# use_flipper! 
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
```