# React Native: compiling error on Xcode with flipper

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am compiling an RN 0.64 app on Xcode for IOS on macOS Big Sur. Using the `Legacy Building System` for `workspace setting` eliminated most of errors but one error with `Time.h` in `Flipper-Folly` remains. I tried to compile with `Xcode 13 beta, 12.5 and 12.4` and all has the same error below:

```
/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app4/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h:52:17: Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')
```

The code in Time.h 52 is:

```
typedef uint8_t clockid_t;  #<<==causing error above
```

The error is under `Flipper=>Schematic issues`. There are several online posts about the similar issue with `flipper` but none of the solution works here.

Comment: Please checkout [my workaround solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70151794/1679361)