# react-native ios "typedef redefinition with different types vs 'enum clockid_t')"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

i'm a newbie in react-native
i downloaded a project from github but i can't run it on ios

i ran `pod install` inside `ios` folder, then i ran `yarn ios`

at the beginning i get

```
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99
```

for multiple pods, i've tried to edit `podfile` but it caused me a lot of problems, so i restored the original one, and reinstalled it.

then i opened ios folder on XCode and edited the deployment target to `ios 14.6` for all the pods, it worked, but now i have another error where i can't find a solution

when i run `yarn ios` i get:

```
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » Conv.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » SysUio.cpp

❌  (/Users/jacopomosconi/app-monorepo/packages/app/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h:52:17)

  50 | #define CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID 3
  51 | 
> 52 | typedef uint8_t clockid_t;
     |                 ^ typedef redefinition with different types vs 'enum clockid_t')
  53 | extern "C" int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec* ts);
  54 | extern "C" int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec* ts);
  55 | #endif
```

someone know how to resolve it?

Comment: same problem... any idea?

Comment: please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66453392/2646158

Comment: checkout this answer, it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/73756361/4592295

Comment: checkout this answer, it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/73756361/4592295

Comment: checkout this answer, it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/73756361/4592295